# Load macro from file to "Playback Macro" (Ctrl+Shift+Q)

Tags: sublimetext3

After writing my first Sublime Text macro and storing it to a `.sublime-macro` file, I expected to be able to load it to the `Playback Macro` button. Unfortunately I haven't found out how to do this and didn't find it under the (un)offical documentation.
Recoding the macro while playing it with `Tools/Macros/User/MyMacro` worked, but I expect there is a more straightforward method.

What would be the proper way to load a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you create a `.sublime-macro` file manually, then you can't use the `Tools -> Playback Macro` option to activate simply because it is not recorded (but something you manually created, which should be listed in `Tools -> Macros` depending on where you stored it in `Packages`).

The option `Tools -> Record Macro` will record a macro (for the current view) and you play it by using `Tools -> Playback Macro` (& optionally save it using `Tools -> Save Macro...`). As far as I can see, the recorded macro will vanish (if not saved) when you close the window (which might mean it's kind of an in memory thing).

If you want to use a macro with a key binding, then there is a command `run_macro_file`. As an example

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+5"],
    "command": "run_macro_file",
    "args": {
        "file": "res://Packages/User/MyMacro.sublime-macro"
    },
},
```